# Music doesn't start when pressing the button in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

The radio should start but I get this in terminal
        E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 0

I don t know exactly what to do I am new in doing this. Before was a problem with Should have subtitle controller already set but it disappears and I have only the problem with state 0 and state 1

```
b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("LOADING");

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (started) {
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                b_play.setText("PLAY");
            } else {
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                b_play.setText("PAUSE");
            }
        }
    });
}

class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        b_play.setEnabled(true);
        b_play.setText("PLAY");
    }


}
```

Comment: You can simply check by `b_play.getText().toString().equals("PLAY)` or `b_play.getText().toString().equals("PAUSE)`

Comment: b_play. doesn t have getText